# Calculate point line distance for a geolocation with altitude

Tags: coordinate-system, geometry, geolocation, mathematics

I'm trying to calculate the coordinates (Latitude, Longitude, Altitude) of a point on a line at the minimum distance with another point.
I was able to calculate the distance using the formula here:
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html
But I want to determine the point on the line where that minimum distance is found.

Comment: Which software are you working with?

Comment: Ideally with Go, but can be any language if I can reimplement the algorithm like I did to get the distance.

Comment: Assuming that the transfer from Cartesian to geographic coordinates (and vice versa) you already have it resolved. A solution in Cartesian space can be found in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/72528.

Comment: Thanks, I can try that. Not sure how it translates into geographic coordinates and if there's anything else to take into account.

Comment: I also need to make sure that the point is on the segment defined and not on the extended line created on that.

Comment: I created a library in Go to do what I needed: https://github.com/emanuelef/go-geo-3d.
That includes the conversion from Cartesian to geographic coordinates and back.
In case the minimum distance point is outside the segment one of the two extremes is returned.